# Access non-wordpress subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've created a sub folder on my root folder along with wp install. Folder is **manager**

However wordpress keeps throwing it to a 404 page when I directly access via URL staging.domain.com/manager. I've fiddled several htaccess changes and so far all got internal 500 errors.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Could this also be a server issue? apache maybe?

Comment: Unlikely. Can you show us the code and exact URL you are using to access it.

Comment: It's on a restricted dev environment. access would be http://staging.domain.com/manager and manager has an index.php file.

Comment: That's not really what I meant - you said Wordpress is giving you a 404 error so I assumed you are linking to the URL from the code. However it appears you mean that you can't access it directly, and that should have nothing to do with WP at all. The only link to WP would be the .htaccess it added to the root, and its fine.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, would server environment be back on the table?

Comment: Possibly, but in most cases its more likely to be something to do with the site setup, e.g. is there a .htaccess in the subfolder, or is there an index file with a redirect? Without seeing your setup, its impossible to know.

Answer (score -2):

its can be done in two step

Step 1 : on your root create index.php with below content

```html
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/manager/wp-blog-header.php' ); /** here manager is place as your folder name */
```

Step 2 : now change "staging.domain.com" to "staging.domain.com/manager" in your database ( for this download sql > open & edit for replace > upload new sql ).

**Now you full site run on staging.domain.com URL but files are call from "manger" folder.**